# VideoView in ViewFlipper is transparent when video is playing

Tags: android, viewflipper, android-videoview, glsurfaceview

I've got an Activity with two views set up in a ViewFlipper. One of the views is a layout with a GLSurfaceView and a few other widgets, the other just has a layout with a TextView and a VideoView. When I click on something in the GLSurfaceView, the ViewFlipper swaps so the video can play. In this screenshot, you can see the plain GLSurfaceView rendering a map on the left. On the right is what it looks like after the ViewFlipper has flipped and the video starts playing.

[image: Screenshot]

The empty transparent area where the GLSurfaceView shows through is where the video is supposed to be. I can hear it playing through the speaker and the timeline is moving forward, so I know it's playing.

I can post code if you need it, but there's a lot involved so it could get rather complicated.

Any ideas as to what's going on here?

Comment: is this happening on device or emulator? because emulator has some issue with playing video.

Comment: On the device. Those are screenshots from my Motorola Droid.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot have two `SurfaceViews` in an activity that overlap, and I suspect that includes cases like `ViewFlipper` where technically they would not overlap due to visibility changes.

Comment: Thanks, that's the problem. I was able to use setVisible(View.INVISIBLE) on the GLSurfaceView to prevent them from overlapping.

Comment: Can you please describe the moment when you toggle it to invisible using `ViewFlipper`? I have a similar issue with simple `LinearLayout`/`VideoView` pair for flipper and even when I hide first layout using setVisibility(INVISIBLE) before or after `flipper.showNext()`, I don't see the video window, but it plays video for sure in background.

Comment: and yes, here's link to [my question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3788497/videoview-plays-ok-but-not-visible-when-swapping-fullscreen-views)