# VideoView plays ok, but not visible when swapping fullscreen views

Tags: android, video, media-player, android-videoview

I have some `AsyncTask` that loads a video stream into the player, so I want to show some Loading screen while it performs. Currently my `onCreate` code looks like this:

```
final View loadingView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.video_loading, null);
final View playerView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.player, null);
final VideoView videoView = (VideoView) playerView.findViewById(R.id.canvas);

Log.d(TAG, "Running video player for video " + videoId);

new VideoPlayingTask(this, videoView.getHolder()) {

    protected void onPreExecute() {
        setContentView(loadingView);
        super.onPreExecute(); // it creates or re-uses (resetting it before)
                            // MediaPlayer instance inside and sets display using setDisplay to the passed holder
    };

    protected void onPostExecute(FileInputStream dataSource) {

        setContentView(playerView);
        videoView.requestFocus();
        super.onPostExecute(dataSource); // it sets data source, 
                                        // prepares player and starts it
    };

 }.execute(videoId);
```

`loadingView` is displayed properly, then when changing content to `playerView`, screen goes black, but sound plays properly in background.

I get these two warnings from MediaPlayer in the logs:

```
info/warning (1, 35)
info/warning (1, 44)
```

I've tried to use `ViewSwither` and to call `showNextView` inside `onPostExecute`, but the behavior was similar, black screen when changing to `videoView`.

I've tried the way with two inner layouts laying inside current and switch their visibility manually, and this also not helped to me.

When I use just single `VideoView` in this activity, it works perfectly and shows both image and sound.

`video_loading.xml`:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:layout_width="fill_parent"
              android:layout_height="fill_parent"               
              android:gravity="center">
    <ProgressBar android:layout_width="@dimen/small_progress_side"
                 android:layout_height="@dimen/small_progress_side" />
    <TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
              android:text="@string/caching_video" />
</LinearLayout>
```

`player.xml`:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:layout_width="fill_parent"
              android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <VideoView android:id="@+id/canvas"
               android:layout_width="fill_parent"
               android:layout_height="fill_parent" />
</LinearLayout>
```

[this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3681976/videoview-in-viewflipper-is-transparent-when-video-is-playing) seems a little bit similar, but switching `loadingView` visibility to `INVISIBLE` does not work in my case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've just used `ProgressDialog.show()` instead of flipping views, it is a lot simpler and `VideoView` handles it right.